# Парсинг авито Python

Tags: python, парсер

Проблема с парсингом последующих страниц, в том варианте, до которого я допер, могу выдернуть только первую страницу, если использовать этот вариант `pagination = soup.find('div', class_='pagination-root-2oCjZ')`, то все вроде хорошо, выводится весь список страниц в html, но как их выдернуть я не понимаю...
Сама страниц - https://www.avito.ru/murmanskaya_oblast/avtomobili/mitsubishi-ASgBAgICAUTgtg3ymCg?cd=1

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_pages_count(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    pagination = soup.find('span', class_='pagination-item-1WyVp').findNext('span')['data-marker']
    if pagination:
       return int(pagination[-2])
    else:
        return 1



def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        cars = []
        pages_count = get_pages_count(html.text)
        for page in range(1, pages_count + 1):
            print(f'Парсинг старницы {page} из {pages_count}...')
            html = get_html(URL, params={"p": page})
            cars.extend(get_content(html.text))
        print(cars)
    else:
        print('Error')


parse()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
URL = "https://www.avito.ru/murmanskaya_oblast/avtomobili/mitsubishi-ASgBAgICAUTgtg3ymCg?cd=1&p="

#Так выглядит твоя ссылка 
#И на каждом шаге цикла меняй свой url 
for page in range(1, pages_count + 1):
    html = get_html(URL + str(page))
    # и далее твоя логика
```

Comment: Это-то даа, а как мне посчитать, сколько всего страниц по ссылке?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, к-во страниц я посчитал так

```
def get_pages_count(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    pagination = soup.find('div', class_='pagination-root-2oCjZ')
    line = pagination.text
    p_count = line[-8]
    print(p_count)
```

Естественно вместо `print` поставить `return`, это касается конкретно авито на момент написания. Возможно будет проблема когда страница будет одна, тк. в этом случае снизу страницы не будет их кол-ва вообще.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать по ссылке ниже получить список объявлений, а дальше уже посчитать количество items в json просто. Не забывай прописывать headers и куки, дабы сайт не заблочил

Ссылка - [https://m.avito.ru/api/9/items?key=af0deccbgcgidddjgnvljitntccdduijhdinfgjgfjir&categoryId=9&params[1283]=14756&locationId=640000&params[110000]=329273&withImagesOnly=1&page=1&lastStamp=1611316560&display=list&limit=30](https://m.avito.ru/api/9/items?key=af0deccbgcgidddjgnvljitntccdduijhdinfgjgfjir&categoryId=9&params%5B1283%5D=14756&locationId=640000&params%5B110000%5D=329273&withImagesOnly=1&page=1&lastStamp=1611316560&display=list&limit=30)

Вот тут есть [статья](https://fox-code.ru/a/kak-sparsit-nomer-telefona-s-avito/) как парсить авито, чтобы не забанили - правда только про номер телефона, но все же кое что полезное там есть.

Вообще парсить Авито через html дело неблагодарное

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]